# Comprehensive list of Amadeus Altéa Error Codes and are error codes available in languages other than English?

Tags: amadeus

Where can I get a comprehensive list of Amadeus Altéa Error Codes and are error codes available in languages other than English ? I have access to the portal.

Comment: Hi @gunc, for questions about Amadeus Altea, you need to put in contact with the Enterprise Account Manager in charge of your company. He will help you for sure. In this channel we only offer support for Self-Service APIs.

Comment: Besides, you can use the following document: https://developers.amadeus.com/support/contact-us-enterprise

Comment: Help me understand, aren't the self service APIs calling Altea, the way the Enterprise APIs do ?

Comment: Hi, Self Service APIs doesn't interact with Altea, but as you say, Enterprise APIs in some cases interact with Altea.